# Por qué pone cin does not name a type y cout does not name a type? Como lo soluciono?

Tags: c++, namespace

Creo que tengo todo el programa bien pero en la compilación me dice

> cin does not name a type
>   cout does not name a type

como se soluciona?

El programa está hecho para introducir la cantidad de colores rojo, verde y azul de una imagen, mostrar los componentes rojo, verde y azul(truecolor) con un registro.

Y con una función pasarlo a escala de grises (la media de todos los componentes, en cada componente) parece muy facil pero me rayo.

---

el programa que he utilizado es:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double grises(int rojo, int verde, int azul) {
  return (rojo + verde + azul) / 3;
};
int main() {
  double gris;
  struct tpColor {
    int rojo, int verde, int azul;
  } cout << "introduce la cantidad de rojo, verde y azul:" << endl;
  cin >> rojo, verde, azul;
  gris = grises(rojo, verde, azul);
  cout << "en escala truecolor es rojo:" << rojo << " verde:" << verde
       << " azul:" << azul << endl;
  cout << "en escala de grises es rojo:" << gris << " verde:" << gris
       << " azul:" << gris << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: si agregas la librería? cin esta en `#include <iostream>`

Comment: @Pablo eso que pusiste en el comentario debe ir en la pregunta, asi como toda la informacion referida que pueda ayudarnos a saber donde esta tu problema. no vemos tu monitor, no sabemos que estas haciendo ni a donde queres llegar, entonces necesitamos que nos guies.

Comment: ya lo he cambiado, alguien sabe que puede ser?

Comment: le he editado la pregunta, intente poner siempre el codigo relevante para la pregunta en formato de texto para que sea mas facil para otros ayudarlo, por otro lado puede mirar para entender como funciona el sitio mas o menos esto -> [tour] y esto -> [ask] para tenerlo en cuenta para formular preguntas futuras. Saludos

Comment: *Se me olvidaba deciros que es lenguaje C* no es `c` es `c++` tenerlo encuenta para poner el tag correspondiente. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus errores son varios de los mas significativos es la declaracion del `struct` sin hacer muchos cambios fijate en el codigo de abajo tienes separados por `,` no por `;`.

Por otro lado no creas ninguna struct solo la defines fijate en esta linea `tpColor tp;`

Cuando hacer rojo por ejemplo este no existe tienes que hacer algo como esto `cin >> tp.rojo, tp.verde, tp.azul;`

donde `tp` es la es la estructura que contiene rojo ect.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double grises(int rojo, int verde, int azul) {
  return (rojo + verde + azul) / 3;
}


int main() {

  struct tpColor {
    int rojo; 
    int verde; 
    int azul;
  };

  tpColor tp;


  double gris; //no tiene ningun "valor

  cout << "introduce la cantidad de rojo, verde y azul:" << endl;
  cin >> tp.rojo >> tp.verde >> tp.azul;
  gris = grises(tp.rojo, tp.verde, tp.azul);
  cout << "en escala truecolor es rojo:" << tp.rojo << " verde:" << tp.verde
       << " azul:" << tp.azul << endl;
  cout << "en escala de grises es rojo:" << gris << " verde:" << gris
       << " azul:" << gris << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

de su cometario:

> en escala de grises es R:-1.39912e+06 V:-1.39912e+06 A:-1.39912e+06

para solventar eso que comenta puede usar algo asi:

```
double grises(double rojo, double verde, double azul) {
  return (rojo + verde + azul) / 3;
}
```

notese `double` en lugar de `int`

y el `struct` asi:

```
struct tpColor {
    double rojo; 
    double verde; 
    double azul;
  };
```

Por otro lado y aunque no es base se esta pregunta le dire que la densidad de cono en el ojo humano no es uniforme a traves de  los colores y
debido a que los seres humanos, no perciben los colores por igual el uso de la media para la conversion a escala de grises digamos que no es "correcto".

Es por ello que alguno editores de de imagenes como GIMP o Photoshop usan algo muy similar a esto:

```
(rojo * 0.3 + verde * 0.59 + azul * 0.11)
```

Otros usan el [Luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29) o ITU-R:

```
(rojo * 0.2126 + verde * 0.7152 + azul * 0.0722)
```

*Nota: si tiene otros errores en su codigo que no estan relacionados con la pregunta inicial lo adecuado es que formule otra pregunta.*

Comment: muchas gracias Angel he puesto lo que tu me has dicho y he conseguido que compile, pero al ejercutarlo he metido 56 67 43 y me sale: en escala truecolor es R:56 V:5 A:-4197420
en escala de grises es R:-1.39912e+06 V:-1.39912e+06 A:-1.39912e+06

Comment: el unico error de lo de angel era  cin >> rojo, verde, azul; cuando lo que hay que poner es >> en vez de las comas, muchas gracias a todos